# How to make sure an object exists before performing operations

Tags: php, oop, class

I have an `index.php` that loads bites of the page from other php files. At the top of the `index.php` I have all the `require_once` statements including the PHP class that handles the db connection and I also instantiate an object of that class:

```
<?php 
    require_once 'libs/DatabaseHandler.php';

    $dbh = new DatabaseHandler('localhost', 'root', '*******', 'pride2012');

    require_once 'pages/01_includes.php';
    require_once 'pages/02_menu.php';
    require_once 'pages/03_slider.php';
    require_once 'pages/04_news.php';   
?>
```

The page-bit using the db managing class is `04_news.php`, is it enough constructing the object before `04_news.php` loads to make myself sure that the object exists before the database related operations start?

Comment: I edited your question to remove your plaintext password, but it will be forever saved in the edit history. In future, be careful not to post passwords (for your own protection).

Comment: I would never give away my password, it was a fake, only to give the idea! ;)

Comment: Feuf! Just thought I'd mention it (it's not obviously a fake password).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining the object prior to the operations is enough.

Alternatively, you can use the built-in `__autoload( )` method to dynamically load classes as needed.

Take a look at [PHP.net: Autoloading Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can try if the object exuits if it's an object and if it's an instance of DatabaseHandler.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php

http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that 04_news.php is never been called alone, aka not by index.php, it's enough.

You can also implement DatabaseHandler as a singleton http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern.